# Tab Fragment Button Click send data to more than one tabFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have three tab fragments TAB1,TAB2 and TAB3. On TAB1 there is a button when when clicked it has to send data to TAB2 and TAB3 using interface and display data in the textView in the respective fragment. So far i have managed to send from TAB1 to TAB2,like below

```
 //  interface  codes
  public interface IFragmentToActivity {
  void Tab1ToTab2(String value);
 }

 //  in activity 

    @Override
  public void Tab1ToTab2(String value) {
TabFragment2 fragment = (TabFragment2) adapter.getFragment(1);
if (fragment != null) {
    fragment.fragmentCommunicationFragment(value);
} else {
    // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment 2 is not initialized");
}
   }


  ///   in TAB1 i send data

          @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button2:
            mCallback.FragmentToFragment("hi from tab 1");
            break;
             }
                   }
```

how can i make it work for all fragments? this is what i have tried when i want to send to TAB2 and 3.

interface codes

```
public interface IFragmentToActivity {
void Tab1ToTab2(String value);
void Tab1ToTab3(String value);
     }
```

TAB1 send data

```
    @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button2:
            mCallback.Tab1ToTab2("hi from tab 1");
            mCallback.Tab1ToTab3(hi from tab 1");
            break;
    }
```

codes in Main Activity to receive

```
       @Override
        public void Tab1ToTab2(String value) {
    TabFragment2 fragment = (TabFragment2) adapter.getFragment(1);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.fragmentCommunicationFragment(value);
    } else {
        // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment 2 is not initialized");
    }
}

@Override
public void Tab1ToTab3(String value) {
    TabFragment3 fragment = (TabFragment3) adapter.getFragment(1);
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.FromFragmentOne(value);
    }

    else {
        // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment 3 is not initialized");
    }
}
```

///  TAB 2 method receive data

```
  public void fragmentCommunicationFragment(String value){
      mTextView1.setText(value);
      }
```

///  TAB 3 method receive data

```
   public void FromFragmentOne(String kabila){
    mTextView1.setText(kabila);
}
```

//  adapter

```
 public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final SparseArray<WeakReference<Fragment>> instantiatedFragments = new SparseArray<>();
private ArrayList<String> mTabHeader;
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
            return tab3;
        case 3:
            TabFragment4 tab4 = new TabFragment4();
            return tab4;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you should use setArgument() and getArgument() in fragment make it in easy way.

Comment: thanks @AniruddhParihar  i  can you please give a sample code on that concept?

Comment: i have posted a code. verify it.

Answer (score 1):

In your Tab1ToTab3 method you're instanciating TabFragment3 with your second fragment :

```
TabFragment3 fragment = (TabFragment3) adapter.getFragment(1);
```

replace it with

```
TabFragment3 fragment = (TabFragment3) adapter.getFragment(2);
```

Comment: thanks @Alexandre BOURETZ for your respond but still   no data displayed in Tab3 though in tab2 displayed

Answer (score 1):

> // Update your getItem() method with this

```
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Bundle bundle =  new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("YOUR_KEY","YOUR VALUE");
                TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
                tab1.setArguments(bundle);
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Bundle bundle2 =  new Bundle();
                bundle2.putString("YOUR_KEY","YOUR VALUE");
                TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
                tab2.setArguments(bundle2);
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Bundle bundle3 =  new Bundle();
                bundle3.putString("YOUR_KEY","YOUR VALUE");
                TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
                tab3.setArguments(bundle3);
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                Bundle bundle4 =  new Bundle();
                bundle4.putString("YOUR_KEY","YOUR VALUE");
                TabFragment4 tab4 = new TabFragment4();
                tab4.setArguments(bundle4);
                return tab4;
            default:
                return null;
        }
```

> // Under TabFragment1, TabFragment2, TabFragment3, TabFragment4
>   Override onActivityCreated() to get your data String and setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) to update view

```
     public static String data;


     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            String yourValue = bundle.getString("YOUR_KEY");
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   TabFragment1.data="Update";
                   TabFragment2.data="Update";
                   TabFragment3.data="Update";
                   TabFragment4.data="Update";
    //update your current View from here
                }
            });
        }



     @Override
        public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
            super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
            if(menuVisible){
                //update your current View from here
            }
        }
```

by using this you can update all fragments data view from any fragment. click

Comment: thanks @Aniruddh Parihar it display pre defined data fine to every fragment but my question was how can i click button from one tab fragment and display value to all fragments.

Comment: or how can i modify it so that it can get value from  tab1 and display to all fragments using such concept thanks @Aniruddh Parihar

Comment: You can do it By Using static variable and setMenuVisibility() method in each fragment.  
If you have Four Fragments the you have  Make Four static variable of your collection or class which contain data, one for each fragment and Override setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) method in each fragment, 
Now in OnClick() of your TabFragment1 you have to update your all four static variable with data which you want to show in all fragment and update the data your of TabFragment1. now when you will go in TabFragment2 then setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) will be called, here you can updat

Comment: sorry if it does not bother you help me with sample codes so that i can get a picture of what you expressing .. am very impressed with your concepts.. thanks

Comment: Pariharhelpme  please help with codes,  this is ma first project   so i get a bit hard to understand exactly what you  express with words  only

Comment: i have updated my code.. please verify it and please voteup and frag as right.